# interacting with Apache in C#

Tags: c#, .net, apache, api

I'm in need of a way of controlling Apache and reading configuration files etc for automating some tasks, does anyone know of any automation APIs or frameworks [much like what Microsoft offers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301438/is-there-a-net-library-or-api-to-interact-with-edit-the-iis-metabase) for IIS?

The application is a C# WinForms app that has a Apache + PHP (WAMP stack essentially). We can't use XAMMP, I need to create virtual hosts etc workout where the php.ini is etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can [reference other apache config files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#include) from the main one; so simply add a reference to your own apache conf file, and then write to it as required; once done, [just restart the apache service](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/win_service.html). Pretty easy.